# How to check disabled service?

Tags: windows-7

I have applied GP for machines to disable windows defender service in win7.
if there any script or command line to check if the service is disabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the service is disabled or not is determined by a registry key.
You can check the registry in vbs with some simple code.  You'll need to find the name of the registry key for the service, though.

```
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
regkey = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<registry entry of service you want to check>\Start"
servicestatus="4" ' 4 is disabled, 0 to 3 means automatic or manual service startup
On Error Resume Next
serviceIsOK = 0
If WSHShell.RegRead(regkey) = servicestatus Then
    serviceIsOK = 1
End If
If serviceIsOK = 1 Then
    'put positive response code here
ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    'put registry reading error code here
Else
    'put negative response code here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Either in **services section** u can control every **Application services**  as u can
 **disable , 
set them to manual , 
Automatic or 
automatic with delayed start.**

U can access services from directly **searching in window search.**

Or Switch to **services tab in Task manager** window and choose appropriate service, right click and choose **go to services**.

It provide very efficient graphical interface for controlling every **windows** as well as **user application services**.